# Carrying attribution from several points to single underlaying polygon to create copies of polygon with unique attribution using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join, one-to-many

I am using ArcGIS Pro to manipulate some property parcels data. I have a parcels polygon layer with the parcel geometry, and a points (PINs) layer with the property attribution information. Most parcels have a single PIN, so I can easily join the attribution from the PIN to the parcel using a one-to-one spatial join.

For those parcels that have several PINs within them, however, I'd like to create one copy of the underlaying parcel for each PIN it contains. I'd like each copy of the parcel to be given the attribution of one of the PINs. I've tried running a spatial join using the one-to-many join operation, but this just creates duplicate copies of the polygon with attribution from the first PIN only. It seems like this should be fairly easy but I haven't been able to find a good solution to this problem.